# Why can't I access my web app from a remote container?

Tags: docker

I have looked through past answers since this is a common question but no solution seems to work for me.

I have a Springboot Java app and a postgresql database, each in their own container. Both containers run on a remote headless server on a local network. My remote server's physical IP address is 192.168.1.200. When I enter: 'http://192.168.1.200:8080' in my browser from another machine I get a 'unable to connect' response.

Here is my Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: aaa
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - nat
  
  web:
    image: email-viewer
    ports:
      - "192.168.1.200:8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - nat
networks:
  nat:
    external:
     name: nat
```

Here is the output when I run docker-compose up:

```
Recreating email-viewer_db_1 ... done
Recreating email-viewer_web_1 ... done
Attaching to email-viewer_db_1, email-viewer_web_1
db_1   | 
db_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2022-05-06 16:13:24.300 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db_1   | 2022-05-06 16:13:24.300 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2022-05-06 16:13:24.300 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2022-05-06 16:13:24.305 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2022-05-06 16:13:24.311 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-05-06 13:54:07 UTC
db_1   | 2022-05-06 16:13:24.319 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | 
web_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
web_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
web_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
web_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
web_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
web_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
web_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.5)
web_1  | 
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:25.487  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.a.emailviewer.EmailViewerApplication   : Starting EmailViewerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.2 on 1a13d69d117d with PID 1 (/app/email-viewer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /app)
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:25.490  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.a.emailviewer.EmailViewerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:26.137  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:26.184  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:26.764  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:26.774  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:26.775  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:26.843  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:26.843  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1297 ms
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:27.031  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:27.077  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.7.Final
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:27.222  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:27.313  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:27.506  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:27.539  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:28.034  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:28.042  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:28.330  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:28.663  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
web_1  | 2022-05-06 16:13:28.672  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.a.emailviewer.EmailViewerApplication   : Started EmailViewerApplication in 3.615 seconds (JVM running for 4.024)
```

Comment: i vote to close as this seems out of scope. However, you may want to start here https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/.

Comment: web:
    image: email-viewer
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
..........
When I enter: 'http://192.168.1.200:8080' ...

See miss configuration ? container port 8080 is opened as 80

Comment: Assuming the server you're running `docker-compose up` has 192.168.1.200 as an IP address, that seems like it's correct (and if it didn't you'd probably get an error before the container actually started).  There's some possible firewalling considerations that are a little beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the embedded tomcat server in spring boot uses port 8080 by default and would require 192.168.1.200:8080:8080 instead of 192.168.1.200:8080:80